# Android ActionBarActivity: ProgressBar in Gingerbread not showing up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

I'm having a weird problem, the progress bar on the action bar is not showing up for older android versions. I've been mainly testing with my phone (4.3) and an emulator (2.3.3) and my phone will display the progress bar, but the emulator wont.

I'm using the AppCompat library, and `ActionBarActivity` which utilizes a drawer layout. The code to get the progress bar is as follows:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);    
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

and then is toggled with the following inside of the fragment.

```
getActivity().setProgressBarVisibility(false);
```

I should also mention that the following is also enabled on the actionbar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Any idea why this works on 4+ but not on 2.3.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `onCreate()` to call support methods instead of standard ones, as:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

And also when you want to display the progress:

```
getActivity().setSupportProgressBarVisibility(false);
```

Comment: supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); is enough if you only need the wheel